# Add SDF to pipeline without having to pass dummy input

Tags: python, apache-beam

I have a SDF written in Python:

```py
class Foo(DoFn):
    def process(element: Pipeline) -> Iterable[str]:
        ...
```

According to docs SDFs are for implementing IO. For my IO I do not need to have input elements passed to the `DoFn`.
The only option to add the SDF to the pipeline seems to be a `ParDo`:

```py
p | ParDo(Foo())
```

Doing it this way fails since it expects a windowing, which is not present. Even when manually adding windowing it still later on fails when making other assumptions.

So how do I write a SDF without any input element and add it directly to the Pipeline?

Answer (score 2):

You can feed in a single record just to trigger that gets ignored by the `Splittable DoFn`.

Alternatively, you can try to use the [Impulse](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Impulse.java) transform.

Comment: We are doing the former currently. Impulse does sound interesting but has the documentation: `For internal use only`